# Doxygen does not create a markdown table

Tags: markdown, doxygen

Doxygen outputs text in place of the expected table. The file text is:

```
/*! \file
    \brief Hardware definitions and macros.


    The processor is an ATmega32U2. The pins and their functions are:

    | Pin | I/O  | Function |
    | --: | :--: | :------- |
    |  1  | I    |  ~RESET  |
    | 28  | P    | VCC      |
*/
```

The HTML output from the table is:

```
| Pin | I/O  | Function || --: | :--: | :------- ||  1  | I    |
```

It's the tilde symbol which causes the problem, after omitting it, the table was output as expected.

Is this a bug or a special feature?

Comment: Problem has been handled on the doxygen mailing list with als answer from Jeremy:
I'm using rev 1.8.5 Doxygen, with MARKDOWN_SUPPORT=YES
After setting the Doxygen factory defaults the table appeared correctly - very odd!
I suggest closing this, and I'll report it again when it's reproducable.

Comment: This works fine for me-- with or out without the first column of vertical bars-- using doxygen 1.8.1. Note that you indeed get no table when you omit the vertical bars on the right and one of the fields in the last column is empty (which is the same as not having the last column and output fails when not every row has the same number of columns).

Answer (score 5):

Works for me with Doxygen 1.8.5 even with the tilde; but the first column of vertical bars must be removed:

```
 Pin | I/O  | Function |
 --: | :--: | :------- |
  1  | I    |  ~RESET  |
 28  | P    | VCC      |
```

instead of

```
| Pin | I/O  | Function |
| --: | :--: | :------- |
|  1  | I    |  ~RESET  |
| 28  | P    | VCC      |
```